# how to import a nuxt component if exist otherwise import a default component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxtjs 2.13.

I finished my default theme and now i wanna add some customization to some of my components without changing the default. so i thought of defining an .env variable like `THEME = 'default'` and in my import component check if `process.env.THEME === 'theme1'` (for example), try to import that component from `theme1` directory.

i also wanna check if that component exist in that directory, import it. otherwise import the default one.

i tried:

```html
<template>
    <component :is="comptest" />
</template>

<script>

export default {
    computed:{
        comptest(){
            let xxx
            try{
                xxx = ()=>import('~/components/${process.env.THEME}/test1.vue')
            }catch(e){
                xxx = ()=>import('~/components/test.vue')
            }
            return xxx
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

and if the component doesn't exist, i get `dependency not found` . also tried this and got the same error:

```js
export default {
    computed:{
        comptest(){
            return ()=>import(`~/components/${process.env.THEME}/test1.vue` || '~/components/test.vue')
        },
    },
}
```

i know i can simply do:

```js
export default {
    computed:{
        comptest(){
            if(process.env.THEME === 'default'){
                return ()=>import('~/components/test.vue')
            }
            return ()=>import(`~/components/${process.env.THEME}/test1.vue`)
        },
    },
}
```

but i wanna know is there a way to check if that component file exist, import; otherwise import something else?! i found out there is something like this for react

Comment: Checking if a file exist can return true while in the next tick it gets unlinked by some random process, thus the import fails with ENOENT ;) , so just use `import(...).catch(default)`

Comment: @Estradiaz , so i should do it like this `return ()=>import('~/components/${process.env.THEME}/test1.vue').catch('~/components/test.vue')` ?? it still gives me dependency not found! also on my last code block i also get this error because even though i return `if(true)` it still check the other import

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    comptest() {
      let xxx
      try {
        xxx = require('~/components/${process.env.THEME}/test1.vue')
      } catch(e) {
        xxx = require('~/components/test.vue')
      }
      return xxx
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nope. it's not working. still gets `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve`